# SQL Server 2008 check constraint not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StateMaster]([StateId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,[StateName] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,[IsDisable] [bit] NOT NULL,CONSTRAINT CHK_StateDisable CHECK *(**IsDisable>=0 and IsDisable<=1**)*,
CONSTRAINT [PK_StateMaster] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [StateId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[StateMaster] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_StateMaster_IsDisable]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsDisable]
GO
```

After executing this insert:

```
insert into StateMaster values ('ABC',***2***)`
```

I get this output:

```
select * from StateMaster


StateId StateName   IsDisable
1       ABC         **1**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not getting the expected output because you are defining the column `IsDisable` as `BIT` which can accept only True/False or 1/0. So For `BIT` datatype all values except `0` and `NULL` is 1.

```
SELECT CAST(NULL AS BIT),
       CAST(0 AS BIT),
       CAST(1 AS BIT),
       CAST(4 AS BIT);
```

Gives you the below result

[image]

So You may try changing the data type of `IsDisable` to `INT` and then try the same insert. Iwillll throw the following error

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 17 The INSERT statement conflicted
>   with the CHECK constraint "CHK_StateDisable". The conflict occurred in
>   database "MyDb", table "dbo.StateMaster", column 'IsDisable'. The
>   statement has been terminated.